# JLabel background distorts while using JXDatePicker

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As soon as I click on `JXDatePicker` (named j in my program code), the `JLabel` (named l1 in my program code) background to which it is added gets distorted. I also tried to repaint l1 whenever mouse is clicked, but, it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

**Program Code :**

```
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.prompt.PromptSupport;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Registration
{
    JFrame stu_reg;
    JLabel back, logo, header, l1, l2, l3;
    JButton sub, cls;
    JTextField t1, t2;
    JFormattedTextField ft1;

    Connection c;

    Registration()
    {   
        try 
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        stu_reg = new JFrame("Student Registration Form");
        stu_reg.setSize(1366,740);
        stu_reg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        stu_reg.setLayout(null);
        stu_reg.setVisible(true);
        stu_reg.setResizable(false);


        header = new JLabel("XYZ");
        header.setForeground(Color.RED);
        HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>  attribute = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
        attribute.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
        header.setFont(new Font("A.C.M.E. Secret Agent",Font.BOLD,30).deriveFont(attribute));
        header.setBounds(350, 0, 800, 75);
        stu_reg.add(header);

        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(Registration.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "xyz.jpg");
        back = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image1.getImage().getScaledInstance(1366, 730, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        back.setBounds(0, 0, 1366, 730);
        stu_reg.add(back);

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Registration.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "R2.gif");
        logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(200, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        logo.setBounds(1100, 0, 200, 200);
        back.add(logo);

        l1 = new JLabel();
        l1.setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 100, 70));
        l1.setOpaque(true);
        l1.setBounds(150, 80, 420, 590);
        LineBorder line = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true);
        Font f = new Font("Scramble",Font.PLAIN,25).deriveFont(attribute);
        TitledBorder title = new TitledBorder(line, "Register", TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.TOP, f, new Color(225,80,0));
        l1.setBorder(title);
        back.add(l1);

        l2 = new JLabel("FULL NAME");
        l2.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD,14));
        l2.setBounds(27, 50, 100, 35);
        l1.add(l2);

        t1 = new JTextField(100);
        t1.setBounds(25, 80, 175, 35);
        PromptSupport.setPrompt("First Name", t1);
        PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.SHOW_PROMPT, t1);
        l1.add(t1);

        t2 = new JTextField(100);
        t2.setBounds(220, 80, 175, 35);
        PromptSupport.setPrompt("Last Name", t2);
        PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.SHOW_PROMPT, t2);
        l1.add(t2);

        l3 = new JLabel("DATE OF BIRTH");
        l3.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD,14));
        l3.setBounds(27, 130, 175, 35);
        l1.add(l3);

        JXDatePicker j=new JXDatePicker();
        j.setBounds(25, 160, 175, 33);
        j.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            l1.repaint();
            }
        });
        l1.add(j);


        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setEnabled(false);


    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( ()->new Registration() );
    }
}
```

**Without Distortion**

[image: Without Distortion]

**After Distortion**

[image: After Distortion]

Comment: [Homoglyphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph) identifiers, like `l1`, can be rather cryptic; when used at all, they should typically have the narrowest scope possible.

Comment: Using a `null` layout is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Define distorted.

Comment: A part of the colored JLabel gets grayed. 
See images http://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZpPR.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/mxbmf.png for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> l1.setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 100, 70));

Swing doesn't support backgrounds with transparency properly. If a component is opaque then Swing expects the background to be opaque, not transparent.

If you want a transparent background then you need to do custom painting.

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and solutions.

Comment: I checked out the link. And, incorporated the suggested change. It works!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First try setting the background color like so:

```
l1.setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 100, 255));
l1.setOpaque(false);
```

Give it a test, does that work now?

If it doesnt work then also remove the following UIManager line at the start of your code `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` and then give it a test again. Often some look&feel's will not allow you to use transparency correctly.

If it works now, then you know that you will either need to abandon the look and feel, or keep it and use custom painting as camickr suggested.

Comment: Either of the statements l1.setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 100, 255)) or l1.setOpaque(false) works. But, they take away the translucency of the JLabel.
Anyway, I tried with what camickr said and it helped.
Thanks!